# Teradat Sql modifiction required

Tags: sql, teradata

```
select * from db.tab1
where PROCESS_DT <= (select max(PROCESS_DT) - interval '72' month from db.tab1
```

The above query gave an error on 29th FEB of this year as there was no 29th FEB last year. This query runs on daily basis to purge 12 months old data. Can you suggest another way to run this avoiding the issue which would arise again in 2020?

Comment: 365 days for regular years, and 366 for leap years?

Comment: yes, as @jarlh mentioned, use CASE expression in WHERE clause to differentiate between your where condition when its a leap year and when its not. I hope CASE with WHERE clause works in Teradata.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add_months` instead:

```
select *
from db.tab1
where PROCESS_DT <= (select add_months(max(PROCESS_DT),  - 72) from db.tab1)
```